# Многопоточный сервер C#

Tags: c#, сокет

Как реализовать многопоточный сервер в приложении? Чтобы можно было присоединять несколько клиентов?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
    IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

    Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    // Назначаем сокет локальной конечной точке и слушаем входящие сокеты
    try {
        sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
        sListener.Listen(10);

        // Начинаем слушать соединения
        while (true) {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Ожидаем соединение через порт" + ipEndPoint.ToString() + "\n";

            // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение
            Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
            string data = null;

            // Мы дождались клиента, пытающегося с нами соединиться

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

            data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

            // Показываем данные на консоли
            //richTextBox1.Text += ("Полученный текст: " + data + "\n\n");
            MessageBox.Show("jsdfhsdfsdf");
            // Отправляем ответ клиенту\
            //string reply = "Спасибо за запрос в " + data.Length.ToString()+ " символов";
            //byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
            //handler.Send(msg);

            if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1) {
                richTextBox1.Text += ("Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.");
                break;
            }

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
            //break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        richTextBox1.Text += (ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему, почему, почему весь код в `OnClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технически, выносить "общение" с клиентом в отдельный поток после Accept. Посмотрите, например, [тут](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm).